# Browserify or Babel inserting special character

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I'm using browserify with babel as a transform. A special character (`Â`) is being added to my own script, as well as other modules in various places. This build/compile is on a Windows machine.

**NPM Build Script**

```
browserify -s appClient source/app-client.js -t babelify > build/app-client.js
```

**Input Snippet:**

```
return (
  <p>Hello,&nbsp;<span
      onClick = { () => setMode('edit') }
      style = { styles.displayMode }
      >{ word }!
      </span>
      <input
        onKeyUp = { onKeyUp}
        placeholder = { word }
        ref = 'wordInput'
        style = { styles.editMode }
      />
  </p>)
```

}

**Output:**

```
Hello,Â world!
```

What's odd is that `Â` gets generated by `&nbsp;`, and not `&nbsp`. So maybe I'm not looking at the build process.

I can manually edit the JavaScript file to remove the special character.

Comment: set the encoding type of the affected files to utf-8 within your IDE. Then add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to your html page. This should solve all problems with wrong characters

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't think JS files were also affected by the meta tag, apparently so! Can you move your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the encoding type of the affected files to `utf-8` within your IDE.

Then add...

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

...to your html page. This should solve all problems with wrong characters.

> **NOTE**: The `meta` tag alone is unnecessary when the content wasn't saved as `unicode`. It only causes the page to interpret all content as `utf-8` (`unicode`).